(LuaLaTeX) What's the best bidi option when having a bidirectional multilingual document?
I'm having a dilemma over whether to use bidi=basic, bidi=default or bidi=basic-r when using both English and Farsi/Persian. I have the follwoing code:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\usepackage[main=english, bidi=default]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import=fa]{farsi}

\setlength\parindent{.25cm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{farsi}
    شیردهی برای نوزادان و مادران مفید است. نوزادانی که با شیر مادر تغذیه می‌شوند، آنتی‌بادی‌هایی را در برابر بیماری‌های رایج از مادر دریافت می‌کنند. کودکانی که با شیر مادر تغذیه می شوند در بزرگسالی شانس کمتری برای چاق شدن دارند. شیر دادن به نوزاد به نوزاد و مادر این امکان را می دهد که به روشی بسیار منحصر به فرد پیوند برقرار کنند. مادرانی که شیر می دهند، احتمال ابتلا به سرطان سینه را کاهش می دهند. معمولا مادرانی که شیر می دهند وزن بارداری خود را سریعتر و راحت تر از دست می دهند. فواید شیردهی بسیار زیاد است.
\end{otherlanguage}

Breast feeding is good for babies and moms. Infants that are breastfed get antibodies from their mothers against common illnesses. Breastfed babies have less chance of being obese as an adult. Breastfeeding a baby lets the infant-mother pair bond in a very unique way. Mother’s who breastfeed lower their chances of developing breast cancer. Usually, mothers who breastfeed lose their pregnancy weight more quickly and easily. The benefits of breastfeeding are numerous.


\end{document}

This displays the document the same if I change the bidi option to bidi=basic, bidi=default or bidi=basic-r. The babel user guide seems to imply that basic is the best option, and that default requires manual input of some sort, but it has a strange description of basic-r.
I should mention that i am using LuaLaTeX. Is basic-r better than default or basic if i have LuaLaTeX? What exactly is the best for my engine? i am not very good at LuaLaTeX but I hope that someone could help me figure this out. I should mention that I don't speak Farsi, I am trying to set this up for a project, but I have dummy text made for this post.

Basically, forget about basic-r. It was a first attempt to create a bidi algorithm. Just follow the advice in the manual and prefer basic. bidi=default works in the 3 basic engines (pdftex, luatex and xetex), with some minimal readjustments for LTR text. If the RTL text only consists of letters and punctuation, it will be fine in most cases, but numbers, for example, will be rendered in the wrong order. This deserves a better explanation in the manual, indeed.
